# Android: how to get link from Atom

Tags: android, rss, atom-feed

I'm making RSS reader for Android but I have problem with Atom. In RSS 2.0 I get link with this:

```
if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
```

and it's made like this:

```
<link>http://wiadomosci.wp.pl/kat,1329,title,Kuratorium-odrzucilo-zastrzezenia-dyrektora-gimnazjum-salezjanskiego,wid,15039916,wiadomosc.html</link>
```

so there is no problem. But in Atom it's made in another way:

```
<link href="http://wiadomosci.onet.pl/media/spor-posla-po-z-wprost-czuje-sie-oszukany,1,5285815,wiadomosc.html"  rel="alternate" ></link>
```

How to get this link?

Comment: What is XPP object ? String resolved from RSS XML ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of versions Rss, Atom etc. You can use Google Feed Api ( https://developers.google.com/feed ) for to get one structure of data for any RSS version or Atom. You just have to  get result (for instance as Json - https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) and parse it.
Hope it will be helpfull.